# Best way to update array with new values by Id

Tags: javascript, performance

Performance is very key and I was hoping there would be a better way to update an array via an Id. I'm looking for a better version of the update function (shown below) that doesn't need to iterate through the 2nd array so many times.

I've added example snippet below to show what I'm trying to do. Keep in mind that these arrays can potentially contain potentially hundreds of objects and need to be updated several times a second.

```js
var array1 = [{
 id:"asd4567wds8",
  x: 109,
  y: 763,
  /* These values also have other properties that I need to keep */
}, {
 id:"df567wgfdz4",
  x: 450,
  y: 132,
  /* These values also have other properties that I need to keep */
}, {
 id: "cvbz5476zzg",
  x: 903,
  y: 865,
  /* These values also have other properties that I need to keep */
}]

var array2 = [{
 id:"df567wgfdz4",
  x: 450,
  y: 137
},{
 id:"asd4567wds8",
  x: 114,
  y: 763
}, {
 id: "cvbz5476zzg",
  x: 908,
  y: 870
}]

$("document").ready(function(){
 display();
  $("#update").click(function(){
   update();
    display();
  })
})

/*************************************
* Is there a better way to do this? *
*************************************/

function update(){
 array1.forEach(function(element){
   var temp = array2.find(function(element2){
     return element.id === element2.id
    })
    
    element.x = temp.x
    element.y = temp.y
  })
}

function display(){
 $("#Array1").empty();
  $("#Array2").empty();
 array1.forEach(function(element){
   var p = $("<span>").text(`[${element.x}, ${element.y}]`)
    $("#Array1").append(p)
  })
  array2.forEach(function(element){
   var p = $("<span>").text(`[${element.x}, ${element.y}]`)
    $("#Array2").append(p)
  })
  if(test(array1, array2)){
    $("#test").text("Success!")
  } else {
    $("#test").text("Values do not match")
  }
}



/* Test function do not change */
function test(array1, array2){
  var clear = true;
  array1.forEach(function(element){
    var temp = array2.find(function(element2){
      return element.id === element2.id
    });
    
    clear = (element.x === temp.x && element.y === temp.y)?clear:false
  });
  
  return clear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="Array1">Array 1: </div>
<div id="Array2">Array 2: </div>

<button id="update">
Update
</button>
<h3 id="test"></h3>
</body>
```

**Context:** I'm creating a game utilizing sockets and I want to update the client with the new locations of the other objects of the game in one huge chunk.

Comment: Should be right under display(). Do you want me to move it up? Eh I'll just move it up. One sec

Comment: Oooooh, there's a scroll bar.  Derp.  With the second code box just below the first I overlooked this.

Comment: Is it possible to restructure your arrays into objects? `object2 = { "df567wgfdz4" : { x: 450, y: 137 }, "asd4567wds8" : { x: 114, y: 763 }, "cvbz5476zzg": { x: 908, y: 870 }` then you can just do `object2[id]`

Comment: @Doug I can actually restructure array2. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: If you infrequently remove from array2, then you can iterate once and store the array2 indices inside the elements of array1.

Comment: I'm still working on Doug's suggestion in my actual code base to see if it has noticeable performance increase but, it does work (https://jsfiddle.net/Mikkal24/fxbpLbwg/2/ )

@rustyx Can you show me an example of what you mean? If you are suggesting stomping the data of Array1 with Array2 I cannot I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also run the map function on one or both of the arrays so that you can get the structure that @Doug mentioned.

```
object2 = { "df567wgfdz4" : { x: 450, y: 137 }, "asd4567wds8" : { x: 114, y: 763 }, "cvbz5476zzg": { x: 908, y: 870 }
```

The map function to get the above would look something like this:

```
array2.map(newObj => {
    var rObj = {};
    var sObj = {};
    sObj['x'] = newObj.x;
    sObj['y'] = newObj.y;
    rObj[newObj.id] = sObj;
    return rObj;
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing drastic performance increases but, this is a much, much cleaner way to handle what I'm doing. I'm going to look for other solutions to my performance issues but, I'll give you guys credit for the answer!

Comment: Thank you for the credit!  I think this will help you with performance as well.  If you convert the second array like above you can then  do something like this in your update function:
`function update(){
        var newArray = array2.map(newObj => {
            var rObj = {};
            var sObj = {};
            sObj['x'] = newObj.x;
            sObj['y'] = newObj.y;
            rObj[newObj.id] = sObj;
            return rObj;
        });
 array1.forEach(function(element){
   element.x = newArray[element.id].x
        element.y = newArray[element.id].y 
    })
    
  })
}`